# IOS app crashes without even entering to my code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, crash

recently my app started crashing without entering my code not sure whats going on I got the below c information from IOS device log, but I am unable to understand this. Someone please help me finding the root cause for the app crash. This happens when i installed the ad-hoc build. but if I install the app from debug it works fine. please help me

```
Sep  3 17:14:21 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] 

<Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: launchd + 85529 [083E000D-4C31-3B98-A2C4-6FADB4D1940F]: 0x3
Sep  3 17:14:21 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SthotraaniiOS[631] <Warning>: Found new TLS offset at 176
Sep  3 17:14:22 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SthotraaniiOS[631] <Warning>: The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.
Sep  3 17:14:22 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SthotraaniiOS[631] <Error>: nw_endpoint_create_address Changing endpoint address length from 28 to 16, too long for family AF_INET
Sep  3 17:14:22 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SthotraaniiOS[631] <Error>: nw_endpoint_create_address Fixing endpoint address with non-zero sin_zero field
Sep  3 17:14:23 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SpringBoard[169] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Sep  3 17:14:23 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SpringBoard[169] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 631: No such process
Sep  3 17:14:23 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SpringBoard[169] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 631: No such process
Sep  3 17:14:23 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SpringBoard[169] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Sep  3 17:14:23 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SpringBoard[169] <Warning>: UNNotificationRegistrarConnectionListener connection invalidated
Sep  3 17:14:23 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 symptomsd[107] <Error>: __51-[FlowAnalyticsEngine _applicationStateMonitorInit]_block_invoke Attempt to add an app with insufficient id, info {
BKSApplicationStateAppIsFrontmost = 1;
BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0;
SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "com.chirravuris.sthotraani";
SBApplicationStateKey = 8;
SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey = 631;
SBMostElevatedStateForProcessID = 8;
}
Sep  3 17:14:23 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 SpringBoard[169] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.chirravuris.sthotraani[0xf3c8]' exited voluntarily.
Sep  3 17:14:23 NarayananugrahamFeb-17-2013 UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 572794164572: id=com.chirravuris.sthotraani pid=631, state=0
```

Comment: answer is posted, check that and please post your app delegate class here @Kris

Comment: @VeerSuthar That warning is there from a long time but that's not the issue, Also I am using xamarin.forms so the window will be created by forms code right ?

Comment: I can't answer that in depth. I put my suggestion, Why don't you try reverting your code, to previous state. You might did something, or reset simulator.

Comment: it's working well in simulator and in my ipad when I install it by connecting to my mac. but not working when I installed Ad-Hoc built IPA. Coming to code changes, it's not entering my code. Any idea whether this caused because of associated domain ?

Comment: I am 100% Sure, you are not setting right Ad Hoc profiles, or structure of make ipa, Kindly read about it, and your question is totally irrelevant. Its profiling issue, not crash before app launches.

Comment: I have correct profile, After seeing your comment I downloaded the profile and built the app but still crashing. I am not getting any ideas :(

Comment: ``AF_INET` endpoint address length from 28 to 16`, are you opening a socket? (socket,https,etc...), trying to use IPv6 localhost? Maybe not disabling UITest code on your release build?...

Comment: No.Not using any IPv6 or socket. Always connects to service with domain name. I have a testfairy call not sure if it opens. But even after removing that same thing happens app crashes.

Comment: nobody has a answer for this ? I just wanted to know what is that error I see in crash log

Answer (score 4):

> : The app delegate must implement the window property if it
>   wants to use a main storyboard file.

This shows that something wrong with your AppDelegate's Windows. Can you recheck your AppDelegate, whether it has Windows object or not.

See below

```
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    public override UIWindow Window
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        // make the window visible
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the issue. I have link all assemblies enabled in ad-hoc build and do not link in debug mode which is causing the app to crash. Moreover that i still see the error shown above but app's not crashing