# IOS app crashes after launch with testflight

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, testflight

I have seen a few similar questions but nothing to help me resolve my issue.

My app works when built in debug mode. It works via testflight on devices running iOS 11+. We support iOS 9 and above, so when i get the app via testflight on an app running iOS 9 the app instantly crashes. I find it unusual that this would run fine on a newer version of the OS but fail on the older version.

I understand that this is a pretty broad question. I presumed it would be an issue with certificates but if that was the case i would expect to see the same issue on each OS version. I have compiled the app for release and ran it on a device to replicate the issue which it does. In the device logs i can see the error.

> Attempt to add an app with insufficient id, info

Again i understand i haven't been able to give much information on this error, but i am hoping someone has been in a similar situation and can give me some pointers.

Comment: Follow this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306638/ios-app-crashes-without-even-entering-to-my-code  may be it's help you!

Comment: Change the linker behavior from "Link all" to "Link Framework SDKs Only" for release configuration, platform iPhone. According to this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95754/ios-app-crashes-after-xamarin-update-to-6-3-build-864-when-distributed-via-testflight which may help you.