# AppleTV app crashes: Attempt to add an app with insufficient id

Tags: xcode, crash, tvos, apple-tv

I am working on an Apple TV app. It does not use xamarin.

I build the project through a Visual Studio Team Services build agent. I install the resulting IPA onto the tv with Apple Configurator 2, but the app crashes on launch.

The device logs (collected with Configurator) show the following error:

```
Apple-TV-2 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[120] <Notice>: 243 com.mycompany.myapp: ForegroundRunning (most elevated: ForegroundRunning)
Apple-TV-2 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[120] <Error>: Attempt to add an app with insufficient id, info {
    BKSApplicationStateAppIsFrontmost = 1;
    BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0;
    SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "com.mycompany.myapp";
    SBApplicationStateKey = 8;
    SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey = 243;
    SBMostElevatedStateForProcessID = 8;
}
```

I have seen the other SO posts with similar device logs, but they appear to be a separate issue ([IOS app crashes without even entering to my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306638/ios-app-crashes-without-even-entering-to-my-code)) which has to do with xamarin.

When I build the project directly with `xcodebuild` (not through a build agent), and install the IPA with Apple Configurator 2 onto the tv, it works like a charm. The problem only persists when the exact same command is used within the VSTS build agent. I have eliminated as many differences as I can find between my normal user's environment and that of the build agent (they are on the same machine, the agent runs on the same user).

Has anyone seen something like this before? Any hints as to where I might look for potential causes/differences between my agent and regular environments? I'm straight out of ideas.

NOTES:

- I am using a `xcodebuild` with xcode 9.2 to build the project.
- I am using the appletv sdk 11.2
- The default keychain has a valid certificate for the project.
- The exportOptions.plist lists a valid provisioning profile for apple tv development.